# Postgres SQL: how to delete rows of Table1 where category = x (but Category is defined in Table 2)?

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I have a Postgres Database. I am trying to delete rows in Table 1, based on a condition expressed in Table 2.

Table 1:
id, object_id, time, action_type

Table 2:
object_id, object_name, object_category

I would like to delete all rows in Table 1, where object_category = x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `in` statement with `delete`:

```
delete from table1
    where object_id in (select object_id from table2 where table2.object_category = x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
delete from table1 
using table2 
where table1.object_id = table2.object_id and object_category = x;
```